# Get mongodb documents with endDate greater than certain date

Tags: mongodb, datetime, go

I am attempting to query my database using Go's mongodb driver to retrieve all documents where the endDate is greater than a date passed in as type time.Time.  I am getting 0 documents returned with my query.

Here are a few of my documents (endDate type in mongodb: Date):

```
_id: ObjectId('6466db9f4795a05298cf860d')
frequency: 1
startDate: 2023-05-18T22:14:14.000+00:00
endDate: 2023-09-30T20:00:00.000+00:00
cost: 12.99
paid: ["2023-04", "2023-05"]

_id: ObjectId('6466e279f708fad7ec8363ae')
frequency: 1
startDate: 2023-05-18T22:44:00.000+00:00
endDate: 2023-11-30T19:00:00.000+00:00
cost: 45.66
paid: ["2023-05"]
```

Here is the query (**date** is of type time.Time and the value is 2023-05-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC):

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"endDate": bson.M{"$gt": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(date)}})
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add some error handling, this may help you figure out why. e.g:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"endDate": bson.M{"$gt": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(date)}})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer cursor.Close(context.Background())

for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
    var result bson.M
    if err := cursor.Decode(&result); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Process the document (result) here
}

if err := cursor.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: When implementing the error handling to log cursor.Err() as you designated Paul, this evaluates to nil and nothing is logged.

Answer (score 0):

The mongo driver handles `time.Time` values as expected, simply use / pass that:

```
cursor, err := collection.Find(context.Background(), bson.M{"endDate": bson.M{"$gt": date}})
```

If this still doesn't return any documents, then `collection` likely designates a wrong collection (possibly in the wrong database), or you really don't have matching documents (check the value of `date`), or the `endDate` property in MongoDB is not of date type.

Comment: I can query for all and get all of the documents, so I am confident the collection designates the correct collection in the correct DB.  Sorry for any confusion.  Also, I have verified that the endDate property of all the documents in the collection are of type Date.

Comment: If none of these help, you must provide more details, aim for a [mcve].